# Failed to detect barcode on embedded device running Android 6.1 using ZBar

Tags: android, barcode, barcode-scanner, zbar

I am trying to detect barcode from an image on my embedded platform using the 'zbarimg' source code. I get no errors while builing the zbar library or zbarimg.c files. However when I try to decode the barcode via 'zbarimg' binary on my embedded device I get the following error:

```
scanned 0 barcode symbols from 1 images in 0.21 seconds

WARNING: barcode data was not detected in some image(s)

  things to check:

    - is the barcode type supported?  currently supported symbologies are:
      EAN/UPC (EAN-13, EAN-8, EAN-2, EAN-5, UPC-A, UPC-E,
      ISBN-10, ISBN-13), Code 128, Code 93, Code 39, Codabar,
      DataBar, DataBar Expanded, and Interleaved 2 of 5
    - is the barcode large enough in the image?
    - is the barcode mostly in focus?
    - is there sufficient contrast/illumination?
```

The same image is getting decoded perfectly in my computer.

Through some investigation, I noticed that the function call "zbar_image_first_symbol" returns null.

How do I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Zbar using nv21 image format coming from camera preview. If you are using another format for image data you must convert it into nv21. You can do it with [easyRS](https://github.com/silvaren/easyrs) library or with manual byte to byte conversion.

Nv21Image nv21Image = Nv21Image.bitmapToNV21(renderScript, result);

After that you can setup zbar library with "Y800" pixel format

Image barcode = new Image(nv21Image.width, nv21Image.height, "Y800");
barcode.setData(nv21Image.nv21ByteArray);

Comment: I am not using camera stream/camera image. I am directly providing a JPEG image to 'zbarimg' binary. Further 'zbarimg' seems to be working fine with my PC with the same JPEG image.

Comment: Yes I built zbarimg in my embedded board as a command line tool.

Comment: zbarimg using ImageMagic as image processor. Is you build ImageMagick for you board? Do you know which version install ? Is Png file with barcode not working too ?

Comment: Yes, zbarimg is using imagemagick. I have built ImageMagick for my board successfully. Yes, when I give png file to 'zbarimg' binary I get an error saying "ERROR: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `JP2' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508". This I suspect is an ImageMagick error. The version of ImageMagick is 7.0.2-5.

Comment: If you build ImageMagic as command line tool, try convert jpeg to jpeg with another quality to check that jpeg encoder working correctly convert image.jpg -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -quality 85 -interlace JPEG -colorspace RGB image_converted.jpg

Comment: Ok, I will try the above to check whether my encoder is working correctly or not. Thanks a ton for your help. I will update you shortly because as of now I do not have a binary named as convert. Will have to tweak my Android.mk files.

Comment: Meanwhile, I have another application using zbar library that works only for PNG images. This application uses 'libpng' library API's to get the image details for PNG image files which are subsequently passed on to ZBar library API's for decoding. Even here, after 'libpng' parses through the image, "zbar_image_first_symbol" returns NULL.

Comment: You must pass image into zbar with properly format, for example "Y800" meaning yuv and doesn't work with result of libpng encoding.

Comment: I checked using convert option and it is working fine on ant jpg image. Yet when I use run 'zbarimg' binary on this converted image I get the same error.

Comment: Additionally my code uses "MagickGetImagePixels(images, 0, 0, width, height, "I", CharPixel, blob)" API to fill an array named blob with image data in grayscale format

Comment: I further dug deeper and found that the function "zbar_scan_image" must return the requisite number of symbols but it isnt.

Comment: Looks like i can't help you without build all you environment from scratch. Btw, main idea is you will pass to zbar data in correctly format. If you pass RGB pixel, you must properly set FOURCC in you initialize code. Take a look at supported format here https://github.com/ZBar/ZBar/blob/master/zbar/convert.c

Comment: Just one thing, why did you ask (in the 4th comment) if I was able to decode PNG images ? Is there any specific reason ?

Comment: I noticed that the function "zbar_scan_image" is responsible for returning the detected symbols from the given image. This function uses a lot of svg function calls such as "svg_open", "svg_image", "svg_group_start" etc. Currently, the calls to these functions do not go throught since "DEBUG_SVG" macro is not present. Is it necessary to define these ? What do they do ?

Comment: I asked about png for sure that ImageMagic correctly installed and working with zbarimg, because all supported format in zbarimg depends of ImageMagic format support list. Is you now try recognize image in SVG format ? If not - just ignore it.

Comment: Thank you for all the help Onix. I have posted the answer to my query below.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the error. Turns out that the config.h file I was using had macros for barcodes commented out i.e. ENABLE_EAN, ENABLE_CODE128, ENABLE_CODE39 were commented out. Because of this the function "zbar_scan_y" (present in 'img_scanner.c' was not able to detect the type of symbols and syms->nsysm would return NULL.

PS: Below is the list of links that will help you port zbar on Android OS.

1.) Source for Android :
https://github.com/ZBar/ZBar

2.) Steps to compile with Android may be taken from : 
http://www.blackdogfoundry.com/blog/zbar-bar-code-qr-code-reader-android/

> Note while compiling using the above steps you may encounter errors of undefined reference. Some source files need to be included in Android.mk file. Further, the patch provided in the above steps will have barcode macros commented out in config.h file.